# Limiting available filetypes for upload with .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm aware of first line, it's obvious, and for second line I think it's only allowing those few extensions, and third line I assume forbids any other filetype.

I'm not sure if my assumptions are correct, and if given htaccess file is forbidding upload of unwanted other filetypes like php or zip, or exe...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.pdf|\.png)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Comment: You assumption is correct but code isn't entirely correct - it will allow files like file.jpg.php as it is missing $ at the end of regexp.

Comment: Can you change it and add as answer? I will correct my question.

Comment: These directives do not forbid the "upload" of anything. It blocks certain URLs being _requested_ (ie. downloaded).

Comment: @user82217 you are correct, I missed the word 'upload'

Comment: @user82217 actually question was edited and word upload was added after my comment.

Comment: To limit what content is uploaded would be up to your application or cgi script to look at either the filename (bad idea, easy to spoof) or the mime type and other attributes about the file to decide if it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet attempts to prohibit access (download) to any files with extensions other than `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.pdf` but as it is missing `$` at the end it allows access to files with these patterns anywhere in the filename, like `file.jpg.php`.

Comment: So proper snippet would be RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.pdf|\.png)$ ?

Comment: @AleksandarPavić yes